# What is the fastest and safest way to backup data on a second harddrive without erasing?

Tags: windows, backup

I have two harddisks.

> HD1: 80 GB
>
> HD2: 1000 GB

On both Harddisks there is data being stored.

I want to move all data from HD1 to HD2 while keeping the previous data in HD2.

So now it is

> HD1: Content1
>
> HD2: Content2

then it should be

> HD1: empty
>
> HD2: Content2 + Content1

or

> HD1: Content1
>
> HD2: Content2 + Content1

to install win7 on hd1 then. So removing Content1 is not necessary in this step as HD1 will be formatted on installation.

What is the fastest, easiest and safest way that you are aware of to backup Content1 on HD2 without erasing any files on HD2?

Comment: Why did you tag this [knoppix]? Also, what OS is *currently* installed on this machine?

Answer (score 2):

Copy + Paste

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> if you're really in a hurry.

Comment: Make sure you paste to a brand new subdirectory on the second disk if you want to make sure you don't accidentally overwrite anything. You may also need to perform some extra steps if the first disk is a system disk and you want a copy of the system files...

Answer (score 0):

If you're backing up a system partition (and its Windows) then the easiest way is to get one of those backup tools and use it to save the entire 80gb disk as an image. Restoring is dead simple then (which is why you're backing it up, right).

If you don't care about restoring and just want to keep your files, then copy+paste to a new subdirectory. Be careful that your paste doesn't stop when it finds a file it can't copy a locked file - Id recommend copying just the necessary directories you need in this case. (actually I'd recommend the image backup)